# MySQL - get min/max of consecutive events in a series of rows

Tags: mysql

I have a table that looks like this:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/152d2/1/0

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (
  id int,
  value decimal(10,5),
  dt datetime, 
  threshold_id int
);
```

Current Query:

```
SELECT sensors_id, DATE_FORMAT(datetime, '%Y-%m-%d'), MIN(value), MAX(value) 
FROM Readings 
WHERE datetime < "2015-11-18 00:00:00" 
AND datetime > "2015-10-18 00:00:00" 
AND sensors_id = 9 
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(datetime, '%Y-%m-%d') 
ORDER BY datetime DESC
```

What I'm trying to do is to return the min/max value in each group, where threshold_id IS NOT NULL. Therefore, the example should return something like:

```
min_value | max_value | start_date          | end_date  
9         | 10.5      | 2015-07-29 10:52:31 | 2015-07-29 10:57:31
8.5       | 9.5       | 2015-07-29 11:03:31 | 2015-07-29 11:05:31
```

I can't work out how to do this grouping. I need to return the min/max for each group of consecutive rows where the threshold_id IS NOT NULL.

Comment: You need to specify what/how you are grouping. Also, what does your query look like at the moment?

Comment: I'm grouping by datetime and my query is this:

SELECT id, DATE_FORMAT(dt, '%Y-%m-%d'), MIN(value), MAX(value) FROM Table1
 WHERE dt < "2015-11-18 00:00:00" AND dt > "2015-10-18 00:00:00" AND id = 9
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(dt, '%Y-%m-%d')
ORDER BY dt DESC

Comment: You're grouping by datetime (down to the second)?

Comment: That's correct, grouping by day really.

Answer (score 1):

Use user variables to compare existing value to the previous value and increment  a column you can use to group by,tested on my machine.

```
SELECT MIN(value),MAX(value),MIN(dt),MAX(dt)
FROM (
  SELECT id,value,dt,
    CASE WHEN  COALESCE(threshold_id,'')=@last_ci  THEN @n ELSE @n:=@n+1 END AS g,
    @last_ci := COALESCE(threshold_id,'') As th
  FROM
    Table1, (SELECT @n:=0) r 
  ORDER BY
    id 
) s
WHERE th!=''
GROUP BY
  g
```

For mysql 8 this could be rewritten as below.Use a CTE to get different sequences and GROUP By the difference between them.

```
WITH cte as (
SELECT *,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id)as rn,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY threshold_id ORDER BY id)as rnn
  FROM Table1
  ORDER BY id
)
SELECT MIN(value),MAX(value),MIN(dt),MAX(dt) FROM cte WHERE threshold_id IS NOT NULL GROUP BY rn-rnn
```

[MYSQL8](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/n74EmdfFbUNDaEmtX5WhuX/0)

[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/152d2/7)

Comment: Thanks for this code! I have managed to achieve exactly what I need from my own project. However, using MySQL 8 I am getting a Warning: _"Setting user variables within expressions is deprecated"_. I've looked at solutions using CTEs and the LAG() function (which replaces @last_ci), but I can't ge to the bottom of it whithout setting @n within the expression... Any idea?

Comment: You probably could ignore user variables altogether in Mysql 8.I edited my answer @HiPierr0t

Answer (score 0):

Your sample data only includes a single day's worth, so you only get a single row back (assuming you want to group by day):

```
SELECT DAYOFYEAR(dt) `day`, MIN(`value`) min_value, MAX(`value`) max_value 
FROM Table1 
GROUP BY `day` 
ORDER BY `day` ASC
```

Comment: Sorry I have simplified my data as I'm working with thousands of rows. In this example grouping by minute would be the same in a smaller scale.